# saving a video with opencv python 3

Tags: python, opencv

I want to save a video after converting to gray scale. I don't know where exactly put the line out.write(gray_video). I use jupyter notebook with Python 3, and the Opencv library.

the code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

video = cv2.VideoCapture("video1.mp4")

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('out_gray_scale.mp4', fourcc, 10.0, (640,  480),0)

while (True):
   (ret, frame) = video.read()

   if not ret:
       print("Video Completed")
       break

   # Convert the frames into Grayscaleo
   gray_video = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   #writing
   gray_frame = cv2.flip(gray_video, 0)
   out.write(gray_video)  #it suppose to save the gray video

   #Show the binary frames
   if ret == True:
      cv2.imshow("video grayscale",gray_video)
    
      #out.write(gray_video)
      # Press q to exit the video  
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break
   else:
       break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What happened when you tried different places in the code to put the line? What's wrong with where you have put it now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the code don't save the video after convert it to gray scale, it only shows the video converted. I need to save the video after convert to public

Comment: is there a video file? how large is it (kilobytes, megabytes)?

Comment: the video has 15 megabites, it is a mp4 file. right now the code only saves a unique frame, not the total video

Answer (score 1):

The working video writer module of OpenCV depends on three main things:

- the available/supported/installed codecs on the OS
- getting the right codec and file extension combinations
- the input video resolution should be same as output video resolution otherwise resize the frames before writing

If any of this is wrong openCV will probably write a very small video file which will not open in video player. The following code should work fine:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

video = cv2.VideoCapture("inp.mp4")
video_width  = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))   # float `width`
video_height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # float `height`
video_fps = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

print(video_width, video_height, video_fps)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('out_gray_scale1.avi', fourcc, video_fps, (video_width,  video_height),0)


while (True):
   ret, frame = video.read()

   if not ret:
       print("Video Completed")
       break

   # Convert the frames into Grayscale
   gray_video = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   #Show the binary frames
   if ret == True:
      cv2.imshow("video grayscale",gray_video)

      #Writing video
      out.write(gray_video)

      # Press q to exit the video  
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break
   else:
       break
video.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: To supplement the answer: https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/